# Big-O complexity of algorithms

Tags: big-o, computer-science

I'm trying to figure out the exact big-O value of algorithms. I'll provide an example:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) // 2N + 2
{
    for (int x = i; x < n; x++) // N * 2N + 2 ?
    {
        sum += i; // N
    }
} // Extra N?
```

So if I break some of this down, int i = 0 would be O(1), i < n is N+1, i++ is N, multiply the inner loop by N:

2N + 2 + N(1 + N + 1 + N) = 2N^2 + 2N + 2N + 2 = 2N^2 + 4N + 2

Add an N for the loop termination and the sum constant, = 3N^2 + 5N + 2...

Basically, I'm not 100% sure how to calculate the **exact** O notation for an algorithm, my guess is O(3N^2 + 5N + 2).

Comment: When using Big-O you omit constants, and all non-highest order terms. In this case O(3N^2 + 5N + 2) => O(n^2). This is because as n grows, those terms are dominated by n^2 and become very insignificant.

Comment: What is `N` in your case? "int i = 0 would be O(1)," --- uhm, nope. Big-O analysis is not when you add up different things in one pile.

Comment: Logically, `i < n` would be `n - 1`, `i <= n` would be `n` and `i <= n + 1` would be `n + 1` . Not that this matters when it comes to Big-O analysis.

Comment: `O(3N^2 + 5N + 2)` is **exactly** the same as `O(N^2)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you mean by exact? Big O is an asymptotic upper bound, so it's  by definition not exact.

Thinking about `i=0` as O(1) and `i<n` as O(N+1) is not correct. Instead, think of the outer loop as doing something n times, and for every iteration of the outer loop, the inner loop is executed at most n times. The calculation inside the loop takes constant time (the calculation is not getting more complex as n gets bigger). So you end up with O(n*n*1) = O(n^2), quadratic complexity.

When asking about "exact", you're running the inner loop from 0 to n, then from 1 to n, then from 2 to n, ... , from (n-1) to n, each time doing a constant time operation. So you do `n + (n-1) + (n-2) + ... + 1 = n*(n+1)/2 = n^2/2 + n/2` iterations. To get from the exact number of calculations to big O notation, omit constants and lower-order terms, and you'll end up with O(n^2) (the `1/2` and `+n/2` are omitted).

Answer (score -2):

Big O means Worst case complexity.

And Here worst case will occur only if both the loops will run for n numbers of time i.e n*n.

So, complexity is **O(n2)**.

Comment: Big O does not necessarily mean worst case complexity. It is a general asymptotic bound. You can also apply it to expected runtimes or any other function.

Comment: Buddy, small o is the not tight bound and Big O is Worst case but tightly bound.
But, Generally we do not use small o to represent worst case complexity. We use Big O to say Worst case bound.

Comment: That's just not true. Big O gives an asymptotic upper bound for an arbitrary function. You can use it to describe the behaviour of whatever function you want. It does not matter if that function describes "worst case complexity per input length" or "average case complexity per input length" or even "worldwide amount of apple consumed per number of people in the world". It's a much more general concept than you think.